# Can't stop postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am string to stop my PostgreSQL (on debian 11) server using the following command

```
root@d11:/# sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 15 main stop -- -m fast -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main
Notice: extra pg_ctl/postgres options given, bypassing systemctl for stop operation
pg_ctl: PID file "/var/lib/postgresql/13/main/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?
```

The notice is correct, the is no such postmaster.pid file, but yes the service is running.  I can confirm it's running with:

```
root@d11:/# sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 15 main status -- -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 2701882)
/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/postgresql/13/main" "-c" "config_file=/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf"
```

So why is my stop command being ignored?  (I tried without the -m fast option but no change, and I'd like to keep that for other reasons).  I confirmed with 'ps ax' that postgresql 15 is running, despite the directory suggesting it might be 13.

Coincidentally, there is a postmaster.pid file in a directory OTHER than the data directory:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/15/main/postmaster.pid
```

(and notice the 15).  Is this a clue?

Answer (score 1):

The command looks wrong:

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 15 main stop \
   -- -m fast -D /var/lib/postgresql/13/main
```

Why do you specify `/var/lib/postgresql/13/main` if you know that the data directory is in `/var/lib/postgresql/15/main`?

Another, simpler way to perform a clean, fast shutdown would be

```
kill 2701882
```

But that would bypass and potentially confuse `systemd`.

Comment: That syntax matches what I found in documentation (so it must be valid - and does not generate a syntax error).  But is there another way to shut it down which allows from proper management of state, pid files, etc.?

Comment: @TSG: well, the _syntax_ might be correct, but the value of the parameters are not. If you are trying to stop Postgres 15, it makes no sense to pass the data directory for Postgres 13 as a parameter. According [to the manual](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/postgresql-common/pg_ctlcluster.1.en.html) you don't even need to pass the location of the data directory. So why not just leave it out. `pg_ctlcluster` should know the correct data directory from the first parameter.